# Yootheme widgetkit user permissions

Tags: joomla, permissions, widget

My clients are restricted in the admin panel of the joomla and theri user group is menager. I need to show them what they need not more than that. But I couldn set the widgetwit permissons for that group there is no option to make that like other components configuration popup screen. How can I show it to the menager user group.

Comment: are you using the free or paid version of the widgetkit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you'll need to allow your component to save permission-related information, then to access the preferences and finally to set the appropriate values.

1. Into the components' folder:  /administrator/components/com_widgetkit/ create config.xml with the code below or edit it to include the "permissions" fieldset.
2. Then add a JToolbar button for preferences anywhere in the component or the view:

   JToolBarHelper::preferences('com_widgetkit');
3. Now in the administrator view you should see the options button.

Comment: You should tell them, I'm not a customer any longer, I just happen to cooperate with a company that uses them; could you accept the answer and upvote?

Comment: Sorry to forgot about the upvote. I did it thanks for reminding and answer. Have a good day.

Comment: Broadly correct but a bit lacking in detail. [This page](http://goo.gl/IaxbQN) has a more complete guide